# Trying to find the starting point to this compounding interest question

Tags: python, while-loop

Question #1: (use while loop only)
An auto repair shop in Miami estimates that, your vehicle will cost $1689 to repair. Assuming that you could not afford to come up with such amount up front, the repair shop offers to let you pay the total repair cost ($1689) by installment, but at an annual interest rate of 3.00% compounded monthly.

Using a while loop,

1. Display the remaining balance after each month until pay off
   Example/Hint: Balance will be $1,493.22 after 1 month.
2. Using the output from item 1 above, determine how many months will the vehicle be three quarter
   (¾) paid off? Use a print statement to display the message.
   Example: "Repair cost total will be 3/4 paid off in 2 months"

I am struggling to figure out how to attack this problem. I'm not sure how to calculate how much each monthly payment will be. There is a hint within the question that in one month, your repair cost goes from $1689 to $1493.22, implying that for the first month, you paid off $195.78 of the repair cost. Any help on how to even start this problem would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this really the WHOLE problem?  There is not enough information in the problem statement to determine an answer.  Saying that the loan rate is 3% per year provides no idea of how long the repair company is willing to accept your debt.  Along with the interest rate there needs to be a monthly payment rate, or else the problem makes no sense.  No wonder you can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to calculate how much the client is paying per month and with that information apply the "compound interest with monthly withdrawals" formula.

To calculate that, you first calculate how much the balance will be after one month with interest:

```py
monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate / 12
balance += (balance * monthly_interest_rate)
```

Now subtract the balance after one month gave as a tip from the balance calculated above:

```py
balance_after_one_month = 1493.22
paid_monthly_by_customer = balance - balance_after_one_month
```